# Cron PHP down after 5 minutes

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I have a domain site created by Codeigniter.
I start the cron PHP with the following code:

```
<?php 
if( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] ) exit();

$argc = $_SERVER['argc'];
$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];

// INTERPRETTING INPUT
if ($argc > 1 && isset($argv[1])) {
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']   = $argv[1];
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $argv[1];
}

set_time_limit(0);

require_once('index.php');

/* End of file test.php */
?>
```

But the script go down always after 5 minutes.
What should I configure to change the time limit?
I have a VPS with Ubuntu 10.04.

I tried to modify the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/<namedomain>.vhost`

```
BusyTimeout 300
```

but the script still fails.
Can you help me?

Comment: What is that script doing?  What are you trying to do?  What do you mean by "fails" and "go down"?  CRON is meant to run a script every X minutes, not keep it running indefinitely.

Comment: Are you trying to run a CodeIgniter controller via CRON?  If you're using CodeIgniter 2, you can do `php /path/to/index.php <controller> <method> <param>`.  See [the docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html).

Comment: like rocket says, your cron should be timed so you don't kill the server. I can't think of many single tasks that would require 5 minutes to execute. Perhaps you should be queuing your tasks instead of batching them. anyhow, andrew sledge has an answer for you. this is just a suggestion.

Comment: >I tried to modify the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/<namedomain>.vhost` >"`BusyTimeout 300`" 300=5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make a PHP script run indefinitely like for a daemon for instance, you would probably want to run it via CLI, and make a linux start up script or whatever that will run your PHP script on bootup instead of trying to use a cronjob.

http://www.debianadmin.com/manage-linux-init-or-startup-scripts.html

http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.commandline.php

Are you new to PHP? Why are you trying to make a script run indefinitely? Typically you would let Apache handle the file requests and script running.

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', <your time in seconds>);
```

Comment: He already has `set_time_limit(0)`, I don't think this will work better.